# jQuery Datatables pagination font size

Tags: jquery, css, datatables

I have a datatable with many entries and it nicely creates pages for me.  However, the "Previous" and "Next" buttons as well as the page numbers are really large.  I cannot find anywhere how to set the font size to make them smaller.

[image: Paging]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it is a non-`inline-block` issue. This should fix. Give this in the CSS at the end:

```css
.dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_paginate .paginate_button.current, .dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_paginate .paginate_button.current:hover {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 10pt;
}
```

Comment: OK, that made the text smaller like I need but the numbers are still overlapping each other.

Comment: @Dean.DePue Did you give `display: inline-block;`?

Comment: Okay, can you try giving: `margin: 10px;`?

Comment: Yes, I did include the inline and the margin command and they are still overlapping each other.  Any other ideas?

Comment: I fixed the overlapping with padding:5px.

Comment: @Dean.DePue Awesome... I thought we need to use the padding here. LoL.